# Form submitting with empty required fields due to use of "placeholder="

Tags: html, forms

My form is tripping up with required fields are able to be submitted without entering anything in the field. I'd like to use placeholder text but it must be reading this as a value, hence the form goes through?

I'm using the html 5 'placeholder' and 'required attributes. email address does get flagged as the placeholder text doesnt match the format i think.

Is there any way to get the form to flag the other required fields?

```
<form action="FormToEmail.php" method="POST" name="Competition">                                                                  
<div id="text">
<input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Name" required placeholder="FULL NAME*"> 
<input class="field" value="" type="email" name="Email" required placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS*">  
<input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Contact-number" required placeholder="CONTACT NUMBER*"> 
<input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Code" required placeholder="UNIQUE CODE*"> 

<p>I have read the Terms and Conditions</p><input type="checkbox" name="Terms and Conditions" value="Selected" required></div>
<p >Read the <a href="competition-terms.html"> Terms and Conditions</a>.</p>

<p>* required field</p>

<input class="btn btn-draw" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />  
</form>
```

EDIT: i recall now that i'm using the javascript below to show the placeholder text in older versions of internet explorer. This script does work for that with the knock on effect of the empty fields submitting. 
I am probably best covered to leave it like this, but i'd be interested if there is any comprehensive solution to ensure placeholder text shows in older browsers and the empty fields are flagged.

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
input.val('');
input.removeClass('placeholder');
}
}).blur(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
input.addClass('placeholder');
input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
}
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
$(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
  input.val('');
}
})
});
```

Comment: Browsers will not read placeholders as values.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: What browsers are you using for this? Additionally are you using any type of plug-in that would do something to your `placeholder` elements via Javascript as the required fields should work as expected (i.e. not be read as values) [as seen here which works in Chrome](http://jsbin.com/sifeji/edit?html,output).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your code: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPRasiqOAhOfrKaRhw0B7efZvrT1ixaQPQ

Comment: There was some javascript included which must have been causing this. Thanks for your answers which have got me back on track!

original post updated, i think this was an ie fix of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you need to prevent the form submit if the input val is equal the placeholder:

```
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function(event) {
$(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
var input = $(this);
if (input.val() === input.attr('placeholder')) {
    event.preventDefault();
    input.val('');
}
```

Are you using any plugin? In which browser is the problem?

The test don't show any problems.

https://jsfiddle.net/mcymnayz/

```
<form action="FormToEmail.php" method="POST" name="Competition">                                                                  
    <div id="text">
        <input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Name" required placeholder="FULL NAME*"> 
        <input class="field" value="" type="email" name="Email" required placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS*">  
        <input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Contact-number" required placeholder="CONTACT NUMBER*"> 
        <input class="field" value="" type="text" name="Code" required placeholder="UNIQUE CODE*"> 

        <p>I have read the Terms and Conditions</p><input type="checkbox" name="Terms and Conditions" value="Selected" required>
    </div>
    <p >Read the <a href="competition-terms.html"> Terms and Conditions</a>.</p>

    <p>* required field</p>

    <input class="btn btn-draw" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />  
</form>
```

Comment: Yes there was something conflicting (edited original post). In removing placeholder="FULL NAME*" for example I was seeing it work which fooled me - whereas it looks to be something else, thanks.